# React component makes a white page

Tags: reactjs, import, components, export

```
import React from 'react';
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import Discussion from './discussion.js';
import Rules from './rules.js';
import Workflow from './workflow.js';

export default function() {
    return (
        <div>       
        hello
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Discussion} />
                <Route exact path="/rules" component={Rules} />
                <Route exact path="/workflow" component={Workflow} />
            </Switch>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I'm importing the function called 'PageContent' from './page-content'

calling it with  in app.js

Then the page goes blank

Comment: Please update your question to include `workflow.js`

Comment: I got it working by installing a previous stable version from 'react-router-dom@5' thnx